# How to structure multi row log data in one row data in python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining, data-cleaning

Following is my data log

```
30/10/2016 17:18:51 [13] 10-Full: L 1490; A 31; F 31; S 31; DL 0; SL 0; DT 5678
30/10/2016 17:18:51 [13] 00-Always: Returning 31 matches
30/10/2016 17:18:51 [13] 30-Normal: Query complete
30/10/2016 17:18:51 [13] 30-Normal: Request completed in 120 ms.
30/10/2016 17:19:12 [15] 00-Always: Request from 120.0.0.1
30/10/2016 17:19:12 [15] 00-Always: action=Query&Text=(("XXXXXX":*/DOCUMENT/DRECONTENT/ObjectInfo/type+OR+"XXXXXX":*/DOCUMENT/.....
30/10/2016 17:19:12 [15] 10-Full: L 2; A 1; F 1; S 0; DL 0; SL 0; DT 5373
30/10/2016 17:19:12 [15] 00-Always: Returning 0 matches
30/10/2016 17:19:12 [15] 30-Normal: Query complete
30/10/2016 17:19:12 [15] 30-Normal: Request completed in 93 ms.
30/10/2016 17:19:20 [17] 00-Always: Request from 120.0.0.1
30/10/2016 17:19:20 [17] 00-Always: action=Query&Text=((PDF:*/DOCUMENT/DRECONTENT/XXXXX/type+AND+XXXXXX.......
30/10/2016 17:19:51 [19] 10-Full: L 255; A 0; F 0; S 0; DL 0; SL 0; DT 5021
30/10/2016 17:19:51 [19] 00-Always: Returning 0 matches
30/10/2016 17:19:51 [19] 30-Normal: Query complete
30/10/2016 17:19:51 [19] 30-Normal: Request completed in 29 ms.
30/10/2016 17:20:44 [27] 00-Always: Request from 120.0.0.1
30/10/2016 17:20:44 [27] 00-Always: action=Query&Tex(Image:*/DOCUMENT/DRECONTENT/ObjectInfo/type+AND+(
30/10/2016 17:20:44 [27] 10-Full: L 13; A 0; F 0; S 0; DL 0; SL 0; DT 5235
30/10/2016 17:20:44 [27] 00-Always: Returning 0 matches
30/10/2016 17:20:44 [27] 30-Normal: Query complete
30/10/2016 17:20:44 [27] 30-Normal: Request completed in 27 ms.
30/10/2016 17:21:09 [25] 00-Always: Request from 120.0.0.1
30/10/2016 17:21:09 [25] 00-Always: action=Query&Text=XXXXXX:*/DOCUMENT/DRECONTENT/ObjectIn
```

This is my data set. There are millions of them. I would like to analyze how long a query took, by whom it came from and how the request looks. The rest I want to hide.

My Expected Output:

```
30/10/2016;17:19:12;Request completed in 93 ms.;Request from 120.0.0.1;action=Query&Text=((PDF:*/DOCUMENT/DRECONTENT/XXXXX....
30/10/2016;17:18:51;Request completed in 120 ms.;Request from 120.0.0.1;action=Query&Text=(("EOM.CompoundStory":*/DOCUMENT/DRECONTE....
30/10/2016;17:19:51;Request completed in 29 ms.;Request from 120.0.0.1;action=Query&Text=(Image:*/DOCUMENT/DRECONTENT/ObjectInfo/type+AND+((.....
30/10/2016;17:20:44;Request completed in 27 ms.;Request from 120.0.0.1;action=Query&Text=XXXXX:*/DOCUMENT/DRECONT....
```

I'd like to solve it in python with pandas if possible. I already have one approach:

```
import csv
import pandas
with open('query.csv', 'rt') as f, open('leertest.csv', 'w') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in reader:
        for field in row:
            if field == "Request":
                    print row
```

But unfortunately without success. Maybe you have a better approach.

I also like to look at new technologies, which do not take long to be learned.

Comment: Not a good idea to parse query.csv with delimiter = ' ' (space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with pandas you can do something like:

```
column_headers = ['Date', 'Time', 'Duration', 'IP', 'Request']
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns = column_headers)
df.to_csv('out.log', index=None, sep=';')

# if you don't want to include a header line, skip the previous lines and start here
for df in pd.read_csv('data.log', sep='\s',  header=None, chunksize=6):
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    df.fillna('', inplace=True)
    d = pd.DataFrame([df.loc[3,0], df.loc[3,1], ' '.join(df.loc[3,4:8]), ' '.join(df.loc[4,4:6]), ' '.join(df.loc[5,4:])])
    d.T.to_csv('out.log', index=False, header=False, mode='a', sep=';')
```

or a non-pandas method:

```
column_headers = ['Date', 'Time', 'Duration', 'IP', 'Request']

with open('data.log') as log, open('out.log', 'w') as out:
    out.write(';'.join(column_headers)+'\n') # skip this line if you don't want to include column headers                                                                
    while True:
        try:
            lines = [next(log).strip('\n').split(' ',4) for i in range(6)][3:]
            out.write(';'.join(lines[0][:2]+[l[4] for l in lines])+'\n')
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Both of the above work in pretty much the same way. They read in from your file (I've named it `data.log`) six lines at a time (since from your example this seems to be the number of lines per group). It then gets the relevant values from each of these lines using either list slices or the `.loc` pandas function.  Finally, it appends the relevant values separated by a `;` to the end of the output file (which I've named `out.log`).

Note that both of these examples avoid loading your entire file into memory at once since that may cause problems/really slow things down if you have millions of lines of data like you say.

**EDIT**

I have updated the examples above to show how to add column headers. If you do not want to add column headers, skip the first three lines of the pandas example and skip the first line after the `with` statement in the non-pandas example.

Comment: Hello banji,
Thank you for your help. Your approach works really well.
I unfortunately forgot something, the columns.
Can you please tell me how I can add columns on the pandas method?
'Date', 'Time', 'Duration', 'IP', 'Request'
Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @harun.  Do you mean how to add the column headers? These would appear as the first line in your output file correct? I will edit my answer to show how to do this with both methods.